# How to get NDK path from the eclipse environment?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-ndk

I am new to eclipse plugin development, I tried of getting the NDK `path` set in eclipse, but there is no way of finding it out. How could I get the `path` of the NDK?

Comment: What NDK are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find where it is set at:

Preferences -> Android -> Native Development

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info but I needed it through an eclipse plugin not manually

Comment: That's the way you get the NDK path on eclipse, regardless of any plugin